# phonegap facebook connect fail on iphone 4 and iphone 5

Tags: facebook, cordova, ios7, phonegap-plugins

I'm developing an ios app with PhoneGap 3.4 which connects to facebook 
I used this plugin to connect to facebook: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin

everything works in emulators provided by xcode 5.1. 
I tested the app on iphone 3gs and the connection to Facebook still works.

tested also with iphone 4s and facebook connection does not work: FB.login is not called. 
the same happens on the iphone 5s.

no error in the xcode console and even in the safari console under developer mode.

the plugin is out of date

Answer (score 0):

Make sure set your config.xml correctly

```
<access origin="https://m.facebook.com" />
    <access origin="https://graph.facebook.com" />
    <access origin="https://api.facebook.com" />
    <access origin="https://*.fbcdn.net" />
    <access origin="https://*.akamaihd.net" />
    <feature name="org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect">
        <param name="ios-package" value="FacebookConnectPlugin" />
    </feature>
```

OR

Use this command to install your facebook phonegap plugin

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin.git --variable APP_ID="XXXXXXXXXXXXXX" --variable APP_NAME=“YOUR_APP_NAME
```

Don't ever use plugman to install cordova plugin.